# capture HLS Stream URL From Webview Android

Tags: android, video, download, streaming, http-live-streaming

so I am trying to get the ".m3u8" link from an Embed Video (JWplayer) programmatically from my java android app,  the source code of the embed page is obfuscated with this "adilbo_HTML_encoder" here's what i get from chrome View-Source :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
    var adilbo_HTML_encoder_DYk ='';
    var hide_my_HTML_WiO=bzIwNFI.WDE1OFg.bTEyOGc.czEwNlM.UDE1NkM.QjIwMGo.dzIxMkQ.SzIwNVY.VjIwNFc.dzE1OFg.bzEyOGE.eTEwNmc.'+'eDEwNVI.bTE1Nk............................etc
```

so trying to get the URL with Jsoup won't work.
what I tried :

1- De-obfuscating the code which was a fail ( if anyone know how please help ).

2-i noticed that Internet Download manager and a chrome extension named "Hls downloader"  on my pc can successfully capture the .m3u8 link then I tried using another network extension named "Network sniffer" to capture the html requests and responses on page load ; I found some requests and responses  to and from the famous wanted ".m3u8" streaming URL which is by the way secured with a token=XXXXXXXX and expiry=XXXXXX , so in my android app i tried to open the embed URL in a hidden WebView and try to get the  streaming URL from there,

I tried using "onLoadResource" and "shouldInterceptRequest" methods to capture the URL but no success
here is my code :

```
  hddwebview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    hddwebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    hddwebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    hddwebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    hddwebview.loadUrl(url);

    hddwebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    hddwebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.contains("/hls/")){
                wantedurl=url;   }

            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        }

     //   @Nullable
    //    @Override
     //   public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
      //      if(url.contains("/hls/")){
                wantedurl=url;  
      //      }
     //       return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);

    //    }
```

So what I need :
a way to get the hls ".m3u8" url From this embed URL ( from my android app ofc )
I searched for a library ( like an advanced browser )or an android opensource video downloader
that can capture the URL Like SNAPTUBE for example.
THANKS.

Comment: There is **some likelihood** I could help here, but I would require use of the **URL** from which you have obtained the `<SCRIPT>` element mentioned in your question.  Using **Google Chrome's** `View Source` button is not usually the same HTML downloaded from the **URL**.  I would have to see if **Java Script** needs to be executed, or if (possibly) the **JSON** would make these **URL's** available.

Comment: here's the link [link](https://www.faselhd.live/video_player?nv2=true&uid=0&vid=782270e633053632ad147a9be256353e&img=)

notice : if you replace "nv2=true" with "nv1=true" in the link and view the source page it views an un-obfuscated  source code with a broken .m3u8 link and the player don't start. the "nv2=true" version gives a unreadable source code but a working stream url.

Comment: Try to play this m3u8 in your Android app : `https://ql8eqt6a.faselhdstream.com/stream/hls/1/782270e633053632ad147a9be256353e/,720,480,360,p.mp4.urlset/master.m3u8?token=EAR7iK6DElarYCmqgqBwpw&expire=1602351627`

Comment: yes this is the URL that I want to get programmatically so I can play it in ExoPlayer2
the problem is how I can get this URL from the embed URL on runtime ( like when the user clicks play on a video ) ? because as u can see the URL is dynamically generated with token and expiry.

Comment: I have to out now (Saturday), I will look at it this evening.

Comment: Well, I returned, checked the **URL**, and all I am getting is the HTTP Code **`"410 Gone"`**.  I mean, I know of two ways that I'm good for executing script.  I also know that often there is a **JSON String** that will contain the link.   I have a tool that can extract a lot more info that **JSOUP** I use, but your **URL** isn't working.    If you message back with an updated **URL** I'll look at it again tomorrow (or Monday).  BTW, if you have **Android** setup, that means you should have `WebView` set up too.  That means you don't need **Selenium** right?

Comment: yes I have a WebView.

update : when I capture all request and response when URL  is loading with my pc, i noticed that all the request that contain the ".m3u8" link that i want are Xmlhttprequest and the `shouldInterceptRequest()` method  can not intercept ajax calls so I think the solution is to find a way to intercept Xmlhttprequests   on the webview. Any idea on that ??

Comment: @M3enar_4bd3lh4k were you guys able to intercept any streaming URLs from webview? Please share your knowledge if you have.